# how to remove on html of jsx element, using map function reactjs

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I have this silly question, my code work perfectly fine, but i have one problem, that i have to add one more

tag, than only it display some thing on to the webpage,

Please read the comment, can any body tell me how to write this code, so i dont have to use two html tag, i dont want to tag, i only need one, 
Please read the commment

```
    showOrderItem(){

                    const orderItems=this.props.orderItems
                    const orderItem=orderItems.map((order,item)=>
                    <p>// if i remove this it wont display me any thing
        { order.quantityEditing?
                        //if i remove these p tag, it will display me the 
            error, adjacent jsx element must be wrapped in closing tag.
                        <p>{order.quantity} {order.itemName}</p>
                        :''

                    }</p>
                    );
    //Please read the comment below
                    return orderItem
                }
```

**and also one more thing,** and for this please give me some link to read, instead of answering it here, 
What does this means that adjacent jsx element must be wrapped in closing tag, my understanding of it -- element should be written in one root element, 
so according to my understaning i added a div tag with written, in this code, but i guess i am wrong what i understood about it, 
Thanks for the time

Comment: React Components must return only a single node, meaning that in any situation in which you have multiple children you want to display, you're always going to have to wrap them in a containing node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some syntax errors.  Shorthand method syntax will not return a value by default if it begins with curly braces.  You can however surround a block with parenthesis to return a value by default, or dont include any braces at all. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

i think this is a correction of your code:

```
showOrderItem() { 
  const orderItems = this.props.orderItems;
  const orderItem = orderItems.map((order, item) => {
    if(order.quantityEditing) {
        return (
          <p>{order.quantity} {order.itemName}</p>
        );
    } else {
        return '';
    } 
  };
  return orderItem;
}
```

Comment: you could probably also just not have the else, jsx should ignore when it tries to render `undefined` . unless you actually wanted the empty string for some reason.